# Spell out the Revu'a

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, unicode

Actually *not* inspired neither by [Atbash Self Palindromes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68757/atbash-self-palindromes) nor by [Generalized Gematria Calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41760/generalized-gematria-calculator).

Given a string *s* of length *n*, output the [Revu'a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria#Methods), which is the first character of *s*, the first two characters of *s*, ... the first *n*–2 characters of *s*, the first *n*–1 characters of *s*, the entire *s*.

The string will only consist of Unicode (any encoding you want) characters that have [strong directionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#strong_characters) and are found in the range 0x0000 through 0xFFFF. However, no directionality control characters will occur. All characters in any given string will have the same directionality.

You may return in array notation `["t","te","tes","test"]`, as a space-separated string `"t te tes test"`, as multi-line text
`t`
`te`
`tes`
`test`
, a pre-formatted array

```
t
te
tes
test
```

, or anything similar. Amounts of leading, separating, and trailing spacing is not important, and neither are trailing newline. Ask if in doubt.

Right-to-Left input must result in Right-to-Left output in proper order:

Input: `"נחמן"`

Output: `"נ  נח  נחמ  נחמן"` or

```
נ
נח
נחמ
נחמן
```

, or `["נ","נח","נחמ","נחמן"]`. Among invalid results are `"נחמן  נחמ  נח  נ"` ,`"ן  מן  חמן  נחמן"`, and `"נחמן  חמן  מן  ן"`.

Comment: 1) shouldn't it be ["ן",‎ "נח",‎ "נחם",‎ "נחמן"]? ‎(2) bonus points if when given that particular string, you finish off with "מאומן".

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn I didn't want to bother people with converting letterforms. And sure, if you implement "m'uman" you'll get cookies ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
η
```

Builtins ftw ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Outputs as a list of prefixes.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Pb//68vuD79@rzr8wE) or [verify all test cases.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/3Pb/Ov9LUotLuK4vuD79@rzr87kS81LiE/PySzJSi@JBMgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
η  # Push a list of prefixes of the (implicit) input-string
   # (and output this list implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 17):

### Dyalog APL, 2 bytes

```
,\
```

Cumulative reduce by concatenate. Try it [here](http://tryapl.org/?a=%2C%5C%27%u05E0%u05D7%u05DE%u05DF%27&run).

The formatting of the output is nicer [when you prefix a `⍕`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2355%2C%5C%27%u05E0%u05D7%u05DE%u05DF%27&run), but it clearly shows the correct order without.

Comment: Exactly the same solution works for the same reason in K.

Comment: @JohnE Does K handle Unicode?

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*Saved one byte thanks to @nicael and @MartinBüttner, one thanks to @Neil*

```js
x=>x.replace(/.?/g,"$` ")
```

Takes advantage of some [built-in features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) of JS's `.replace` function. Specifically, in the replacement, `` $` ``  becomes everything preceding the matched character. Using the regex `/.?/g` rather than `/./g` means it also matches the empty string at the end.

Comment: I saved another byte: `f=x=>x.replace(/.?/g,"$` ")`. You get an extra leading space but that's allowed.

Comment: @Neil Thanks, I had no clue that would work!

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to quote my \` properly, but I see you worked out what I meant.

Answer (score 6):

## Japt, <s>10</s> 4 bytes

I didn't realize that a cumulative reduce would be so useful in this case. :-)

```
U¬å+
```

Outputs as an array, comma-separated by default. If this is not allowed, use this 6-byte code instead:

```
U¬å+ ·
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VazlKw==&input=Ilx1MDVlMFx1MDVkN1x1MDVkZVx1MDVkZiI=)

#### How it works

```
      // Implicit: U = input string
U¬    // Split U into chars.
  å+  // Cumulative reduce: loop through each item in the array, concatenating it to the total.
      // ["t","e","s","t"] => ["t","te","tes","test"].
      // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: Is using the phrase "Try it online!" and not linking to [Try it online!](http://tryitonline.net/) morally acceptable? :P

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'd been using that phrase in Japt answers for about a month before Dennis trademarked it. I feel I should have some moral right to keep using it :P

Answer (score 6):

### Retina, <s>11</s> 7 bytes

```
.
 $`$0
```

Output is space-separated, with a leading space and a trailing linefeed.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LgogJGAkMA&input=16DXl9ee158)

Comment: For posterity, it's portable to Perl for 5 more bytes : `perl -pE 's/./$`$&\n/g'`. (I'm 11 months late, I know)

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 40 bytes

My console doesn't support Right-to-Left characters, but I don't think it will work :c

```
++++++++++>,[>,]<[<]>[[<+>-]<[<]>[.>]>]
```

Ungolfed:

```
++++++++++> # Store 10 (Newline)
,[>,]       # Store input
<[<]>       # Goto first character
[           # While next character
  [<+>-]    # Copy character to the left
  <[<]>     # Goto first character
  [.>]      # Print all charaters
  >         # Go to next character
]
```

Comment: You can post them as separate answers.

Comment: You **should** post them as separate answers.

Comment: You ***must*** post them as separate answers.

Comment: You ***WILL*** post them as separate answers.

Comment: You _**CONVINCED**_ me to post them as separate answers.

Comment: 1. People on the interwebs _**CONVINCED**_ me to improve my post by creating seperate answers.
2. SO asked me if I was sure. They said I could use the edit link to improve my answer.
3. I told SO I was sure.
4. SO asked me again.
5. I told SO I was still sure.
6. SO told me they didn't allow robots.

Discrimination against robots, SO is getting sued!

Answer (score 4):

## Prolog (SWI), <s>60</s> 49 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(X):-findall(S,atom_prefix(X,S),[_|R]),write(R).
```

**Explained:**

**atom_prefix** with **X** set to input and **S** as a variable gives 1 prefix of the atom **X** starting with the empty atom.

**findall** gets all solutions and puts them in a list.

**[_|R]** throws away the head (the empty atom) and stores the tail in **R**

**Examples:**

```
p('נחמן').
[נ, נח, נחמ, נחמן]

p('test').
[t, te, tes, test]
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/HdptFMQA.pl)

**Edit:** saved 11 bytes by only storing the tail in **R**.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 35

```
f=lambda s:f(s[:-1])+[s]if s else[]
```

Couldn't find a way to use `and/or` to simplify the recursion because `[]` is falsy.

Recursive solution, returns a list of strings.

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/d1wDve)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 3

```
._z
```

Prefix builtin does the trick.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=._z&input=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%9F&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%9F%0Aa%0Aabcd&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## GNU Sed, 21

Score includes +1 for `-E` option to sed:

```
:
s/^(\S+)\S/\1 &/
t
```

<strike>Works for LTR, but not RTL - I missed that bit.</strike>.  Actually it *does* work, the RTL was just not rendering correctly in my terminal.  It works fine with IO viewed in a sensible text editor (e.g. emacs).  It also works in Ideone:

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/fk4Qo1)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
@[@w\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=QFtAd1w&input=Iteg15fXntefIg)

#### Explanation

```
@[       Take a prefix of the input
  @w     Write this prefix to STDOUT followed by a linebreak
    \    False: try another prefix
```

Right-to-left strings seem to work properly, even though I never even considered them.

Comment: Why non-competing?

Comment: @Adám `@[` and `@w` were implemented necessarily after April/May 2016. One could find the exact date on the Github commits but it surely isn't before this challenge was submitted.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 9 bytes

```
l{N2$@+}*
```

Output is linefeed-separated.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%7BN2%24%40%2B%7D*&input=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%9F)

#### Explanation

```
l     e# Read input.
{     e# Fold this block over the input, which is effectively a foreach-loop which skips
      e# the first character...
  N   e#   Push a linefeed.
  2$  e#   Copy the previous string.
  @   e#   Pull up the current character.
  +   e#   Concatenate.
}*
```

Comment: I totally expected CJam to be shorter than that.

Comment: @Timwi There is neither a "get all prefixes/suffixes" built-in nor a higher-order function for generalised accumulation, so even if this isn't optimal I doubt it can be beaten significantly.

Comment: `Ll{+_p}/;` is same length, posting because I'm not sure if someone with more experience might be able to golf it more, and also maybe fix the quotes thing :P

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 36 bytes

```
x=>[...x].map((c,i)=>x.slice(0,i+1))
```

Demo:

```js
a=x=>[...x].map((c,i)=>x.slice(0,i+1));
document.write(
  a("test")+"<br>"+
  a("נחמן")
)
```

The principle is to map and output the slice of string from the first char to the every char in the word. Surprisingly, this works perfectly for the RTL strings too, no optimization needed.

Answer (score 2):

### TI-BASIC, 18 bytes

```
For(X,1,10^(9
Disp sub(Ans,1,X
End
```

Not technically valid: TI-BASIC doesn't support Unicode.

Name this `prgmA`, and input using `Ans`.

Program recursion would be shorter, but there would be no way to initialize the variables. Therefore, we display a substring of the input at each iteration. The input is never overwritten, since Disp doesn't return a value.

Eventually, the program terminates with an error after printing the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

My console doesn't support Right-to-Left characters, but I don't think it will work :c

**C, 74 bytes (2nd entry)**

```
char m[2<<9];i;main(){do{m[i]=getchar();printf("%s ",m);}while(m[i++]>0);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// char, because `printf("%s", str);` expects a array of characters.
char str[2<<9];
int  str_len = 0;
int main(void) {
    do {
        str[str_len]=getchar();
        printf("%s ", str);
    } while(m[i++]>0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My console doesn't support Right-to-Left characters, but I don't think it will work :c

**C, 105 bytes (3th entry)**

```
m[2<<9];i;j;k;main(){while((m[i++]=getchar())<0);for(;j<i;j++,putchar(10))for(k=0;k<j;k++)putchar(m[k]);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int str[2<<9];
int str_len = 0;
int main(void) {
    do {
        str[str_len] = getchar();
    } while(str[str_len++] != EOF);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<str_len; i++) {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
          putchar(str[j]);
        }
        putchar(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 54 Bytes

```
b='';y=input()
for a in range(len(y)):b+=y[a];print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>95</s> <s>92</s> 58 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=0;;)System.out.println(s.substring(0,++i));}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dY@xbsIwEIZ3nuLkyVZKxFyLbh0YSgfGqoMxpjUEJ8qdUVHk52Cjfas8Tuo4oUthOcmn///u804d1XS32Xe6UIjwoqxrJgDWkam3ShtY9k@AY2k3oPmKaus@AIWM2zCJA0mR1bAEB/MOp0/Ntqx5rIOdz6QUqxOSOeSlp7yKVSocxxz9GhOIzx6yzAohQyd7WOXXRYSNzHTzEI3Gs2/voMSgQwaJs36ypHLdtD/tub203@yfYIKl0N8fBtQNQ7ZwladHYBmO9FuhV09D6mpQnxqXax47QSvSn/z5S5uKbOnAiCbcA42qofsF)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                        // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;              //  Index-integer, starting at 0
      ;)                    //  Loop indefinitely:
    System.out.println(     //   Print with trailing newline:
      s.substring(0,++i     //    Increase the index by 1 first with `++i`
                       ));} //    And print an input-substring in the range [0,i)
```

Stops the infinite loop with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` after everything has been printed to STDOUT already, which is [allowed according to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/52210).

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 8 bytes

Uses [current version (8.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/8.0.0) of language/compiler

```
jtn1X"YR
```

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > jtn1X"YR
 >
> test
t
te
tes
test
```

#### Explanation

```
j           % input string
tn          % duplicate and get length, say "N"
1X"         % repeat string N times vertically. Gives a char matrix
YR          % lower triangular part of matrix. Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
#<>#2&~FoldList~Characters@#&
```

TODO: explanation

Answer (score 1):

## , 7 chars / 16 bytes

```
ᴉⓜᵖ ᵴ˖$
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%9F&code=%E1%B4%89%E2%93%9C%E1%B5%96%20%E1%B5%B4%CB%96%24)</kbd>

There's probably a builtin for this somewhere - I just haven't found it.

## Explanation

```
ᴉⓜᵖ ᵴ˖$ // implicit: ᴉ=split input, ᵴ=empty string
ᴉⓜ      // map over ᴉ
   ᵖ ᵴ˖$ // push ᵴ+=(mapped item char)
         // implicit stack output, separated by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 29 bytes

```
(a,b='')=>[...a].map(x=>b+=x)
```

This ain't winning anything, but it's a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 Bytes

```
Vlz=k+k@zNk
```

[Try It Out](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vlz%3Dk%2Bk%40zNk&input=test&debug=1)

***Explanation***

```
(z=input)
(k="")
V        for N in Range(
lz       length of z):
=k+k@zN     k=k+z[N]
k           print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and f(s[:-1])+" "+s
```

Recursive function that outputs a space-separated string with a leading space.

A 34-byte program (Python 2):

```python
s=""
for c in input():s+=c;print s
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
òÄ$xh
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w7LDhCR4aA&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh)

Explanation:

```
ò       " Recursively:
 Ä      "   Duplicate this line
  $     "   Move to the end of this line
   x    "   Delete one character
    h   "   Move one character to the right, which will throw an error when the line is one character long
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 28 bytes

```
[char[]]$args[0]|%{($o+=$_)}
```

Takes input `$args[0]`, casts it as a `char`-array, pipes the characters into a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we accumulate onto `$o` via `+=` the current character `$_`. That expression is encapsulated in parens so a copy is placed on the pipeline. At end of execution, the pipeline is flushed via `Write-Output` which puts a newline between elements.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\spell-out-the-revua "נחמן"
נ
נח
נחמ
נחמן

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\spell-out-the-revua "PPCG"
P
PP
PPC
PPCG
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 17 bytes

```
.[:range(length)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/18v2qooMS89VSMnNS@9JEMz9v9/pYzUnJx8pX/5BSWZ@XnF/3WLAA)

-10 from ovs.

Comment: `.[:range(length)]` works for 17 bytes. There is a way to save 2 more bytes, but I'll leave that to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 59 Bytes

```php
for(;$i++<mb_strlen($argn);)echo"\n".mb_substr($argn,0,$i);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34c6bf3768ceea746ad250f2d99745189a1bbe19)

Answer (score 0):

## [Unwanted, Unnecessary, Opportunistic](https://github.com/faso/Unwanted-Unnecessary-Opportunistic), 9 bytes

```
E<+S0;*P
```

Answer (score 0):

## [.+?](https://github.com/EdgyNerd/DotPlusQuestion/blob/master/README.md), 18 bytes

```
^((.+).)
\2\n\1
$
```

## Explanation

```
^((.+).)   Replace the first line with
\2         The first line missing the last character
  \n       A newline
    \1     The first line
$          Repeat until the regex doesn't match (when first line has 1 character)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BTsMwEEX3c4qRKKrdFKsOO4RP0gQpRW5jkToj24B6EnbArXIc46FR1N3Mn/efhi6pH/1jzu5MY0gYL3GLwQKF8YSGV9WF08detyrS4JJYN34tAdwRB@sFY/K@NkY/ATpPhgNFIwkJdoj2mt6K6raUOdnBZ@8Gi4429fPi4sKxPKDOXXrt/7M9E@2WRXyehQWJ74dbYBkrPdMME1YGNeD8DdsdGbPjGQ/Bdm9X6oGpO6TgfBKlXAxFsKwy5/wihKqkktDUjW80rCBPv9PX9D39/AE) (The second command line argument is input)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 2 bytes

```
iT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/0/M@R/bW50brVmYO3/kNTiEq7rC65Pvz7v@nwA)

```
iT # Generate inits
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

Courtesy to a'_' for saving two bytes by removing redundant bits!

```
:i,,{)i<}/
```

Nice short and cute response :)

```
:i,,{)i>}% #Revu'a Sequence
:i           #Remember the input as i
  ,,         #Array from 0 to i-1
    {   }% #Block, for each element, map this
    {)  }% #Increment the number by 1
    { i }% #Move i to the top of the stack
    {  >}% #Print the characters less than the index i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvVJJaXKL03ypTR6daM9OmVvV/wn8A)

Comment: [GolfScript, 10 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvVJJaXKL03ypTR6daM9OmVvV/wn8A). [Explanation.](https://tio.run/##ZY69CsJAEIT7PMWgCAaSoG2wSWEhWAi@gGfcJAeXvXC3KUR89hjzZ@G237czU1pT@NzpRrqVkJdVl2rMt0bmvS4ZUhE0N61ALHQARNGinIlLqWKnuKQEmXPqicLZGjskCQzxVofxPvjKr/nnKsoJFGrVwFjbpANGOOET545qYhmKua3v5EYDejQura9@qyaGwxhOhvI@3Zi@3fteU/zv4r3p3SM/lhHdrfsA) (Because < isn't order-sensitive, and you can return as a list.)

Comment: Oh, durr! Didn't even think about doing listwise comparisons - mental slip there, good find!

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
¦
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%A6&inputs=Among%20Us&header=&footer=)

But that's boring, so here's something a bit more interesting:

### 6 bytes

```
żƛw?$i
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C5%BC%C6%9Bw%3F%24i&inputs=Among%20Us&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
żƛw?$i  
        # Implicit input of string
żƛ      # Over each integer n in range(1, len(input) + 1):
   ?    #   input[
  w $i  #         :n] (python indexing)
        # Implicitly print the result of the above.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5MiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMiVENyVBMCVENyU5NyVENyU5RSVENyU5RiUyMiZmbGFncz0=)

```
ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMiVENyVBMCVENyU5NyVENyU5RSVENyU5RiUyMiZmbGFncz0=)

Built-ins for prefixes.